# Godot Error: Top-level statements must precede namespace and type declarations

Tags: c#, godot

I'm learning how to use Godot following the "**Your first 2D game**" from this document: https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/getting_started/first_2d_game/03.coding_the_player.html#preparing-for-collisions
While I got the end of the chapter which is "**coding the player**" as the link redirected. I tried to play the game I've created so far. But it turned out **several errors** which I have no idea how to deal with:

1. Top-level statements must precede namespace and type declarations.
   From line "EmitSignal(nameof(Hit));"
2. The modifier 'private' is not valid for this item.
   Also from line "EmitSignal(nameof(Hit));"
3. The modifier 'public' is not valid for this item.
   From line "Show();"

My code in Player.cs is as follows.

```
public class Player : Area2D
{
    [Signal]
    public delegate void Hit();
    // Declare member variables here. Examples:
    [Export]
    public int Speed = 400; // How fast the player will move (pixels/sec).

    public Vector2 ScreenSize; // Size of the game window.

    // Called when the node enters the scene tree for the first time.
    public override void _Ready()
    {
        ScreenSize = GetViewportRect().Size;
        Hide();
    }

  // Called every frame. 'delta' is the elapsed time since the previous frame.
    public override void _Process(float delta)
    {
        var velocity = Vector2.Zero; // The player's movement vector.

        if (Input.IsActionPressed("move_right"))
        {
            velocity.x += 1;
        }

        if (Input.IsActionPressed("move_left"))
        {
            velocity.x -= 1;
        }

        if (Input.IsActionPressed("move_down"))
        {
            velocity.y += 1;
        }

        if (Input.IsActionPressed("move_up"))
        {
            velocity.y -= 1;
        }

        var animatedSprite = GetNode<AnimatedSprite>("AnimatedSprite");

        //no more fast diagonal movement.
        if (velocity.Length() > 0)
        {
            velocity = velocity.Normalized() * Speed;
            animatedSprite.Play();
        }
        else
        {
            animatedSprite.Stop();
        }
        // The delta parameter in the _process() function refers to 
        //  vv        the frame length - the amount of time that the previous frame took to complete.
        Position += velocity * delta;
        Position = new Vector2(
            x: Mathf.Clamp(Position.x, 0, ScreenSize.x),
            y: Mathf.Clamp(Position.y, 0, ScreenSize.y));
            
        if (velocity.x != 0)
        {
            animatedSprite.Animation = "walk";
            animatedSprite.FlipV = false;
            // See the note below about boolean assignment.
            animatedSprite.FlipH = velocity.x < 0;
        }
        else if (velocity.y != 0)
        {
            animatedSprite.Animation = "up";
            animatedSprite.FlipV = velocity.y > 0;
        }
      }
    private void _on_Player_body_entered(object body)
    {
        Hide(); // Player disappears after being hit.
        EmitSignal(nameof(Hit));
        // Must be deferred as we can't change physics properties on a physics callback.
        GetNode<CollisionShape2D>("CollisionShape2D").SetDeferred("disabled", true);
    }

    public void Start(Vector2 pos)
    {
        Position = pos;
        Show();
        GetNode<CollisionShape2D>("CollisionShape2D").Disabled = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you include the top level statements `using Godot;` and `using System;` at the top of your file?

Comment: Could you share the full error you are getting? because "Show();" public modifier does not make any sense. Is this the correct file and or the latest version?